# monacaにあらかじめDBを内包する

Tags: monaca, sqlite

monacaでのアプリ制作をしています。
こちら（http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/sampleapp/tips/storage/#creating-a-database-sqlite）
のサンプルソースでDBを作り値を保存する方法はわかったのですが、もともとDBありきのアプリを制作する方法がよくわかりません。

DB内に問題と答えを格納しておきそれを参照するようなものが作りたいのですが、どのように作れば良いのでしょうか？
対象はandroid&iOSで考えています。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

私のやり方は、アプリ初回起動時にテーブルを作成し、`INSERT`文を実行して初期データを登録します。
初期データは、`INSERT`文に直接記述するか、json形式などのファイルから取り込み`INSERT`文を実行する形となります。
アプリ初回起動は`db.version`の値で判断し、空の場合、`db.changeVersion()`を実行して`1.0`に書き換えます。
その際に、テーブル作成と初期データの登録を行います。
アプリのバージョンアップの際に、テーブル変更や追加データ登録などにも簡単に対応できます。

```
var db = window.openDatabase("testdb", "", "testdb", 1024 * 1024);
// 初回起動か？
if (db.version == "") {
    db.changeVersion("", "1.0",
        function() {
            // テーブル作成・初期データ登録
        }, function(err) {
            // バージョン変更失敗
        }, function() {
            // バージョン変更成功
        });
}
```

Comment: なるほど初回起動で作成されるようにつくるのですね、なるほど